# Lack of exit stamp & passport database update for travel from Nepal to India by road

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, indian-citizens, passport-stamps, nepal

Long story but hear me out.

4 years back I travelled from India to Nepal via Air.
Indian Citizen.
Bangalore - Delhi - Kathmandu route.
Passport was stamped with Departure stamp in Delhi and was subsequently stamped with Arrival one at Kathmandu.
Spent about 5 days in Nepal and came back to India(Bihar state) via road. Now this was super early morning after an overnight bus journey followed by a cab journey with my friend's extended family, with all of us going to my friend's house in Bihar.
I remember with my sleepy eyes that no one asked for Identification at the checkpost and the cab driver just did the needful by informing the check post at the Indian side about the occupants. Stayed in Bihar for a week and back to Bangalore.
Now after all these years, I'm applying for a tourist visa to Thailand and unsure if lack of entry stamp to India/Passport database not being updated will cause a concern at Immigration counter while leaving India.

I know Indians dont need a visa to visit Nepal but this specific instance has gotten me worried.

Comment: This is in some sense unanswerable—the only way to find out for sure if you will get a visa or not is to apply for one and see if you get it or not—but it doesn't sound particularly likely to be a problem to me. If you have other proof that you returned to India when you say you did, you could submit it, I guess, but sometimes passports are not stamped on exit, an Indian citizen can't violate immigration law by going between Nepal and India, and the Thai authorities probably don't care about any of this anyway.

Comment: Why would Thailand care about the lack of an entry stamp for India? Also Indian citizens can get a visa on arrival in Thailand. So if anyone is going to ask, it's going to be immigration at the airport in India.

Comment: You say that the bus driver did what was required when you arrived in India. If that is the case, surely there should be no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Nepal is under a free-movement agreement with India

[1950 India-Nepal Treaty of Peace and Friendship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Nepal_Treaty_of_Peace_and_Friendship)

> ###### Article 7
>
> The Governments of India and Nepal agree to grant, on a reciprocal basis, to the nationals of one country in the territories of the other the same privileges in the matter of residence, ownership of property, participation in trade and commerce, movement and other privileges of a similar nature.

The fact that you didn't get stamped by land will not get you into any type of issue